# Is it possible to fetch emails from pop3 using sign in with google rather than app password?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am fetching emails from pop3 with `app password` which is working perfectly fine. Can I replace `app password` with `sign-in with google`? I am using `enough_email` package.
I am done like this:

```
await popClient.connectToServer(host, port, isSecure: true);
await popClient.login(email!, token!);
```

and signing with google like this:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
User? user;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final GoogleSignInAccount? account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication = await account.authentication;
final AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
 accessToken: authentication.accessToken,
 idToken: authentication.idToken,
);
final UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
user = userCredential.user;
```

I already tried to login with `accessToken` and `idToken` but getting `PopException -ERR [AUTH] Username and password not accepted`

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the following documents

https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

that leads me to the right direction. To authenticate client using sign-in with google. Here is my code for reference:

```
ImapClient imapClient = ImapClient();
await imapClient.connectToServer("imap.google.com", 993, isSecure: true);
await imapClient.authenticateWithOAuth2(user, accessToken);
await imapClient.selectInbox();
final FetchImapResult result = await imapClient.fetchRecentMessages();
List<MimeMessage> mimeMessages = result.messages;
for (MimeMessage mimeMessage in mimeMessages) {
  print(mimeMessage.decodeTextPlainPart());
}
await imapClient.disconnect();
```

*user*: email address

*accessToken*: google sign-in authentication token